# How to remove all the properties (INVOCATION/INBOUND/OUTBOUND/SESSION) in a specific scope in mule

Tags: mule, transformer-model

I am having a problem where my rabbit mq message put is erroring and it does not tell me what the root cause for the put failure is. Looking at stackoverflow, I see that my problem is identical to what was reported here-[to store a message in rabbitmq from mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674040/to-store-a-message-in-rabbitmq-from-mule)-as far as exception goes. 
Now I am trying to find out if there is a way to remove all the properties present in the message or if the removal can be performed per scope (i.e. INVOCATION/INBOUND/OUTBOUND/SESSION). Reason being, I dont know which property, if at all, is causing this.

I did look at `<remove-property>` & `<message-properties-transformer>` but they work on a specific property only (& not all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that `<remove-property>` works on specific properties **only**? i recall using this transformer with a wildcard to achieve something similar to what you are trying to do:

```
<remove-property propertyName="*" doc:name="Property"/>
```

Comment: Tried this and it worked. It actually removed all the properties that were present in the OUTBOUND scope.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with this inside a Groovy Transformer:

```
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope
message.getPropertyNames(PropertyScope.OUTBOUND).each {p -> message.removeProperty(p, PropertyScope.OUTBOUND)}
```

I would be looking at scopes OUTBOUND and SESSION, as the other scopes shouldn't be propagated over a transport boundary.